# notifications don't show up using jquery ajax get

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

i want to display the notifications on a page, so i used window.setinterval function that contains an AJAX get method !

**header.asp**

```js
window.setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getnotifications.asp',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'javascript',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
   return data;
        }
    });
}, 10000);
```

**getnotifications.asp**

```html
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<% Response.Charset="UTF-8" %>
<!--#INCLUDE file="connect/site_conn.asp" -->
<!--#INCLUDE file="connect/members_conn.asp" -->
<!--#INCLUDE file="connect/notifications_conn.asp" -->
<!--#INCLUDE file="global.asp" -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.growl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/jquery.growl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<%
Dim rsGetLatestNotifications
Set rsGetLatestNotifications = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strSQLData = "SELECT * FROM TB_NOTIFICATIONS WHERE NOT_TO = " & mem_id & " AND NOT_READ = false"
strSQLData = "" & strSQLData & ";"
rsGetLatestNotifications.CursorType = 2
rsGetLatestNotifications.LockType = 3
rsGetLatestNotifications.Open strSQLData, adoConNotificationsData

Do While not rsGetLatestNotifications.EOF %>
   <script>
   $( window ).load(function() {
          $.growl.notice({ message: "The kitten is cute! hahaha" });
    });
    </script>
  <%
    rsGetLatestNotifications.MoveNext 
Loop

rsGetLatestNotifications.Close
Set rsGetLatestNotifications = Nothing   

adoConNotificationsData.Close
Set adoConNotificationsData = Nothing
adoConSiteData.Close
Set adoConSiteData = Nothing
adoConMemData.Close
Set adoConMemData = Nothing     
%>
```

the code doesn't work and i know something is missing ! pls i'll be grateful if you help me

Comment: Try to work with JSON, it's more simple: https://code.google.com/archive/p/aspjson/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% Dim member Set JSONdata= jsObject()
Do While not rsGetLatestNotifications.EOF %>
   JSONdata("message") = "The kitten is cute! hahaha"
   rsGetLatestNotifications.MoveNext
Loop
JSONdata.Flush
%>

window.setInterval(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'getnotifications.asp',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(JSONdata) {
         $.growl.notice(JSONdata);
    }
});
}, 10000);
```